# dialog for pass (unix password manager) disappeared

Tags: arch-linux, password-store, artix-linux

I recently migrated from Arch to Artix Linux and the GUI dialog for `pass` disappeared. I need to get it back.

In Arch, `passmenu` launches a GUI dialog to insert the password for the gpg keys, but in Artix `pass` or `passmenu` only opens terminal dialogs. That means I can't launch a password prompt dialog from scripts or from keybindings. T

This is very inconvenient because if I want to login into a website I have to open a terminal just for that (in Arch, it would open a floating dialog in the middle of the screen to type the password, which is very convenient).

I bet there is a package for opening such GUI dialogs, but I don't know which package. Does anyone know the package?

**Note**: the packages from Arch's repository are avaialble on Artix too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing package is `gtk2` or `gtk3`